# Как скопировать пользовательский массив (аргумент функции) в другой массив?

Tags: java, android, массивы, firebase, arraylist

Я получаю данные с базы Firebase в массив с помощью следующего кода. Так как данные не могут быть использованны за пределами `onDataChange`, я использовала [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774) решение и вот, что получилось:

Функция

```
private void readDate(final FirebaseCallback firebaseCallback) {

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for( DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                OrderDetails details = postSnapshot.getValue(OrderDetails.class);
                orderList.add(details);
            }
            firebaseCallback.onCallBack(orderList);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Интерфейс

```
private interface FirebaseCallback {
void onCallBack (List<OrderDetails> list); }
```

Теперь, когда я вызываю функцию в onCreateView, данные есть, но доступны они только внутри фунции `readDate()`. И, как я понимаю, мне нужно скопировать данные в другой массив. Я создала новый массив:

```
List <OrderDetails> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

И теперь в функции пробую скопировать данные в этот массив, но не получается:

```
readDate(new FirebaseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCallBack(List<OrderDetails> list) {
       orders.addAll(list);
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "size: " + orders.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "sizenew: " + orders.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Но опять данные не доступны за пределами функции (Toast - "size: 8" - внутри функции и 'sizenew: 0' - за пределами функции). Не понимаю как это решить, уже второй день ломаю голову над этим вопросом. Буду благодарна за любые вожможные решения.

Comment: Возможно что вы копируете не в тот список, у которого проверяете размер потом, проверьте области видимости переменных, или приведите более целостный пример классов

Comment: Toast за пределами функции вызывается до Toast внутри. Потому что когда вызывается readDate(...) то код "в ней" выполнится не сразу, а только когда будет получен ответ с сервера firebase- через секунду или через час, но всегда позже чем   Toast вне функции. Будь иначе приложение бы зависло ожидая ответа. Следовательно в Toast вне функции массив orders сначала пуст, затем получен ответ и массив заполняется.